# Brightness adjustment gone

Tags: windows-10, brightness

I have a W10 all-in-one desktop that I use, I used to have a little brightness button in the action center where I could adjust the brightness. (I could also right click and manually adjust a slider in settings)

I opened my computer and noticed that it was stuck at a specific brightness (even if it said 25% or 100% it didn't actually change the brightness)

So I restarted my computer and to my astonishment - it's gone!

Gone, meaning there is *no way* for me to change my brightness now.

> - I checked Action Center - gone
> - Power options - gone
> - Search settings for "brightness" - nothing.

Did some new update happen? This was never an issue before.

---

I just noticed that my **Night Light** button is greyed out:

[image]

And the settings for it are greyed out as well:

[image]

I assume they are related.

> Note: the Night-Light settings, although it doesn't work, it at least came up. *The brightness settings won't even come up*.

Comment: You might find a keyboard shortcut for screen brightness... check the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to open device manager, go to monitors, open **Generic PnP Monitor** and Roll-Back the drivers. (from 2010 to 2006 `:/`)

I'm hoping that they'll fix this soon.